# Xcode Post Build Copy File Actions

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

In Xcode, how can I call a 'shell script' which is a Perl script that copies the `.app` and `.dsym` files to a different directory?

I want to pass the name of the project and/or the project's root directory to the script. I want to have the script called every time I build in release and distribution modes but not in debug mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on your target and choose Add->New Build Phase->New Run Script Build Phase.

Inside the "Script" text area, add:

```
if [ ${CONFIGURATION} != "Debug" ]
then
    /usr/bin/perl "${PROJECT_DIR}/myperlscript.pl" "${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
fi
```

Change the location and name of `myperlscript.pl` to be the location and name of your script.

Make sure to move the `Run Script` step to be after `Link Binary With Libraries`, since you're copying the built .app.

(Might also want to add the "perl" tag to the question)

Comment: Cool. Thanx.
I didn't tag it with a language because I'm guessing I can substitute the perl part of the command line to use php or python or whatever else.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else who is wondering, you can also do a simple copy via

[Click on Scheme Name] -> Edit Scheme... -> [Select Scheme] -> Run "Target" -> Post-actions

and add a cp command.  In my case, for quick testing and ease of use, I wanted to copy my binary back to the project directory so that I could process some data files.  I used the following:

```
cp ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME} ${PROJECT_DIR}/"binaryFileName"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a script, Xcode 12.4 has an build phase for copying files:

1. Show the project navigator (blue folder button)
2. Click on your project (blueprint icon)
3. Click "Build Phases" header in the opened settings pane
4. Click the + in the top left of the settings pane
5. Click "New Copy Files Phase"
6. Change Destination to Absolute Path and set your path
7. Click the + at the bottom to add a file to be copied
8. **Save**. If you run without saving, your new phase **is ignored**.

If you don't want an absolute path or one of the destinations provided, you'll have to use a Run Script Phase instead.