# How can I deploy an app to my iPhone from the command line?

Tags: iphone, build-automation

I can already build an app with a distribution profile via the command line

```
xcodebuild -configuration Distribution -sdk iphoneos3.0 clean build
```

However, I'd like to go one step further and install the app to the connected iPhone and execute it ( as if I'd pressed Build and Run in XCode ).

The final command listed in the build commands window ( cmd+shift+B ) is CodeSign, which as far as I know just signs the code and nothing else. So I'm not sure what command ( if any is available ) I can run from the command line to install and run the app on the iPhone.

I'm running the official SDK, not a jailbroken phone.

Comment: How does this not belong on Stack Overflow? It's a development question, and should be here, not on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [post build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331517/xcode-post-build-copy-file-actions) you should be able to install it and run it using a script.  If you're jailbroken you should be able to use SCP and then execute it directly.

There may be an [AppleScript](http://macosx.com/forums/software-programming-web-scripting/281932-scripting-xcode.html) or [automator](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/automatorforxcode.html) way of solving the problem as well.

Comment: It's not clear to me what command would perform the installation.

Comment: If your jailbroken and have OpenSSH installed you should be able to:

scp -Crp $APPDIR/build/Release-iphoneos/Example.app root@$IPHONE_IP:/Applications/

Comment: Personally I just ncftp the application to my FTP server so I (and my testers) can fetch it later:

#!/bin/sh
cd "$HOME/src/bidding_practice/trunk/Personal Bridge Scorer/build/Release-iphoneos"
zip -pr PBS.zip Personal\ Bridge\ Scorer.app
echo "put PBS.zip" | ncftp mywebsite
rm PBS.zip

#!/bin/sh
rm -f PBS.zip
wget http://mywebsite.com/PBS.zip
unzip PBS.zip
rm -f PBS.zip
rm -rf /Applications/Personal\ Bridge\ Scorer.app/
mv Personal\ Bridge\ Scorer.app/ /Applications/

You could set up thed SSH to run the pull script automatically.

Comment: On gitgub there's a project called iPhoneSim that allows you to control publishing and debugging in the simulator:

http://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog entry on how to install apps on a connected iPad / iPhone without using Xcode or iTunes. This method does NOT require JailBreak - any iOS device will work. Only works on the Mac though.

This method allows you to run a Terminal command to install an iPA file.

http://pervasivecode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/install-ios-app-ipa-file-without-xcode.html