# Auto copy .app to Applications folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6, post-build-event

When I click Product -> Archive for a Mac app in Xcode 6, I want the .app file to be automatically copied to the Applications folder replacing the earlier copy.

I've noticed there are post build actions for the Archive scheme but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode Post Build Copy File Actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331517/xcode-post-build-copy-file-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will want to add a custom shell script phase. 
You could do any number of things there.