# Xcode Build path and copying additional files

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I'm writing a plugin for Elgato Stream Deck. https://developer.elgato.com/documentation/stream-deck/sdk/overview/

Basically it is a binary command line tool written in C++/OBJ-C/Swift combined with a JSON manifest and optionally some HTML and JS files as well as different assets (.png, ...). All files have to be included in a folder (com.companyname.pluginname.sdPlugin) which lives in Library/Application Support/com.elgato.StreamDeck/Plugins/

At the moment, I'm building the binary to the default build path (derived data, ...) and manually copy it to the above folder. But I need to build and run that binary with an executable (Stream Deck app) defined in the scheme for debugging under Xcode. The JSON manifest and assets also lives in my xcode project folder and have to be copied manually.

So Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

So my question: how can I automate that under Xcode? I assume I can do some sort of post build scripting, but I have no knowledge about all that stuff.

Thanks

Comment: How to add a script after build https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331517/xcode-post-build-copy-file-actions for the rest, copy/pasting a file/folder can be done in Bash/Shell, look how to, you can try in `Terminal.app` until you succeed.

Comment: just precised my question. I need to run the binary with an executable as well.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

- go to target -> build settings
- Deployment Location = YES
- Installation Build Products Location = / (empty this one!)
- Installation Directory = path to folder (= $INSTALL_PATH)
- this will copy your binary to the defined installation path
- go to target -> build phases
- new phase -> run script
- `cp -r "$SRCROOT"/<FILE OR FOLDER NAME> "$INSTALL_PATH"/<FILE OR FOLDER NAME>`
- repeat this for all files and folders you need to be copied to the installation path. be careful with empty spaces in the folder/file names, they won't be recognized correctly and you have to use quotation marks